# Why does gdb output fatal error?

Tags: go, gdb

I am studying to use gdb to debug Go program. The Go version is 1.2, and runs on linux/amd64.

The Go program is very simple:

```
package main  
import "fmt"
func main(){
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

When using gdb to debug it, the gdb output is

```
$ gdb hello
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /data2/home/nanxiao/hello...done.
Loading Go Runtime support.
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x400c00: file /data2/home/nanxiao/hello.go, line 3.
Starting program: /data2/home/nanxiao/hello

Temporary breakpoint 1, main.main () at /data2/home/nanxiao/hello.go:3
3       func main(){
(gdb) n
runtime: pc=0x400c13 0xcc 0xeb 0x48 0x83 0xec
fatal error: runtime: misuse of rewindmorestack

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x56325f)
    /data2/soft/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:464 +0x69
runtime.rewindmorestack(0xc210001148)
    /data2/soft/go/src/pkg/runtime/sys_x86.c:41 +0xb4
runtime.newstack()
    /data2/soft/go/src/pkg/runtime/stack.c:230 +0x153
runtime.morestack()
    /data2/soft/go/src/pkg/runtime/asm_amd64.s:225 +0x61
```

Per my understanding, after running the "n" command, the gdb should go the next statement, and the output is:

```
fmt.Printf("hello, world\n");
```

Why does it output the following "fatal error"?

```
runtime: pc=0x400c13 0xcc 0xeb 0x48 0x83 0xec
fatal error: runtime: misuse of rewindmorestack
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: I don't think it'll make a difference, but what happens if you use gdb command `run` instead of `start`?

Comment: @NathanErnst: After using "run" command, the program exits successfully.

Comment: Not being familiar with the `start` command, I would then suggest looking into the gdb environmental differences between `start` and `run`.

Comment: This issue is a known issue, and please refer https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=6776.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was an issue with version 1.2. It's fixed in version 1.2.1, you can download it from: https://code.google.com/p/go/downloads/list